# Example where convergence in measure does not implies convergence in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

This is an example from my Real Analysis class:

Consider the space
$(\mathbb{R},L,m)$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Let $f_n = n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$.

So $\int |f_n| dm = \int_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]} n dm = 1$

But $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, so $m(|f_n - 0| \geq \epsilon) \leq m((0,\frac{1}{n})) = \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$

Thus convergence in measure does not imply convergence in $L^1$.

My question is: Why is $m(|f_n - 0| \geq \epsilon) \leq m((0,\frac{1}{n}))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\{ x \mid f_n(x) \neq 0\} \subset [0,\frac{1}{n}]$

Comment: Ah ok, I see it now. I needed to write it out and then I was forgetting that I'm looking for the set of $x$, not $n$. Thank you